# CALayer gets redrawn frequently despite shouldRasterize --> why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, instruments

I have some fairly complex layers in a part of my app and I want them to rasterize as their content changes close to never. The frame of the view these layers are in can be changed by dragging a "spacerbar" around with your finger.
I made a simple test-app to visualise my problem and show you some code:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    UIView* m_MainView;
    UIView* m_TopView;
    UIView* m_BottomView;
    UIView* m_MidView;
    int m_Position;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)loadView {
    m_MainView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    m_TopView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    m_TopView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    m_TopView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    m_BottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    m_BottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    m_BottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    m_MidView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    m_MidView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    m_MidView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [m_MainView addSubview:m_TopView];
    [m_MainView addSubview:m_BottomView];
    [m_MainView addSubview:m_MidView];

    CALayer* targetLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    targetLayer.frame = CGRectMake (100, 200, 500, 50);
    targetLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor;
    targetLayer.shouldRasterize = true;
    [m_BottomView.layer addSublayer:targetLayer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [m_MainView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    m_Position = 400;
    super.view = m_MainView;
}
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    float touchY = [sender locationInView:m_MainView].y;
    m_Position = (int)touchY;
    [m_MainView setNeedsLayout];
}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect bounds = super.view.bounds;
    m_TopView.frame    = CGRectMake (0, 0, bounds.size.width, m_Position - 10);
    m_MidView.frame    = CGRectMake (0, m_Position - 10, bounds.size.width, 20);
    m_BottomView.frame = CGRectMake (0, m_Position + 10, bounds.size.width,
        bounds.size.height - m_Position - 10);
}
@end
```

[image: ScreenShot].

Now ... By using instruments and activating "Color Hits Green and Misses Red" one can see when a layer is redrawn (is then highlighted in red).
In this example the bar (targetLayer) is green (cached) most of the time, but if I start dragging the spacer (which in fact changes the frame of the bottom-view) the layer turns red some times ... especially if I reverse the direction of the drag or if I drag slowly.
In my app this causes flickering as redrawing these layers is expensive.

Why does this happen??
I never change any property of the layer but it gets redrawn anyways?
I am sure I am missing something :-)

As a workaround I could make a snapshot of the layers and use the image ... that would work I think and if there is no solution I will have to use this approach but I would like to understand what is the problem here.

Anyone?